# VBA Find function won't find exact match

Tags: excel, vba, find, match

I have code that will loop through Array values and find each element of the array in the worksheet and then when found output the element to a button. This works mostly quite well although I have a peculiar problem.

[image: This is my range on the worksheet]

[image: This is the array being found (FilterGet)]

[image: This is the output]

Now clearly the issue is that for some reason the first output isn't the first item from the array. The array `FilterGet` is built from user input when they type in a string that is then searched and organised into most likely output based on the user input. However when the user inputs something simple like "the" it doesn't take the actual entry that it matches exactly to?

It works fine with more complex inputs but any short strings if they match with the worksheet won't appear first even if they match exactly in place of something that doesn't match exactly.

This is the code -

```
Dim p As Long
Dim FilterFind As Range
Dim DataCapture As String
    
    For p = 2 To UBound(FilterGet) + 2
    If p = 9 Then GoTo EndPhase
        With Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:C" & Row)
            Set FilterFind = .Find(FilterGet(p - 2), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not FilterFind Is Nothing Then
    
                    DataCapture = FilterFind.Offset(0, -1).Value & " " & "-" & " " & FilterFind.Value & " " & "-" & " " & FilterFind.Offset(0, 1).Value
    
                    Controls("CommandButton" & p).Caption = DataCapture
                End If
        End With
    Next p
```

Any idea why its behaving like this?

Comment: Try to define also _LookAt_ and _MatchCase_ for the [find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) operation.

Comment: Ahh I thought xlWhole would prevent it from finding entries where the string provided is only part of the string in the range much like 'Match entire cell content'. But it seems to work fine with it. Thank you